# Automatically login to Twitter

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm doing a little experimentation. The end goal is to open Twitter in a new tab for a user that is already logged in.

I have gone down the oAuth route and I can post to twitter, retrieve tweets etc. but when I visit Twitter.com I still get the login page. I have a couple of questions

A) Is it possible to automaticaslly log a user in like this (I can see why it can't be but need to make sure)
B) Does anyone know of another way to acheive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you redirect the user to twitter to authorize, send them to *oauth/authenticate*, instead.

This flow is called [Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/sign-in-with-twitter).